# escaping double quotes in string without back-slash

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I program with C# in visual studio, I would send the following string with SerialPort:

```
AT+CWJAP =  "text1"  ,  "text"
```

my code is :

```
string a = "AT+CWJAP=";
string b = "\"text1\"";
string c = "\"text\"";
string y = "a + b +  ","  +  c";v
```

but the result is: `y = "AT+CWJAP=\"text1\",\"text\""`
I don't want to send the backslash `(\)`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
string a = "AT+CWJAP=";
string b = "\"text1\"";
string c = "\"text\"";
string y = string.Format("{0}{1},{2}", a, b, c);
```

The value of Y will be: AT+CWJAP="text1","text"

Comment: with MessageBox(y) it is the right code displayed , but when sending on SerialPort , the backslash still exists, it's necessary that I could simply remove (\)